# What Linux library supports sockets, ioctl calls, tuntap, etc...?

Tags: c++, c, linux

What is the name of the runtime library which implements Linux network interfaces, like sockets, tuntaps, netlink, etc...? For example when I create an UDP socket and make an ioctl call to fetch network interface info, which library actually implements that call? What are the corresponding *.so files on most linux dstirbutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are c library calls, and as such are in the libc library.

Answer (score 1):

The C library exports the functions, but they are just wrappers for sys calls. The actual socket functions themselves are implemented inside the kernel.

So pull it to pieces starting with sys_socket - it's not that difficult, and [LXR](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.32/net/socket.c#L1266) makes it easy.

Answer (score 0):

They're not all in libc, although many are.  Tun/Tap has its own library, so does netlink.  Basic socket operations are in libc.